# SQL delete command advice using c#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, command

On click button presents the following code,
For some reason it wont delete data from database, (the dropdownlist is valid) any advice or changes needed?

```
protected void deleteback_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    // declare variables
    String EditNewID = DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Value;

    // set connection string to database
    String connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ScrumString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection myConnection2 = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

    // delete values to product backlog
    myConnection2.Open();
    String query = "DELETE * FROM product_backlog WHERE product_backlog.id = @id ";

    SqlCommand commanddelete = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection2);

    commanddelete.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", EditNewID);

    // refresh page
    Page.Response.Redirect(Page.Request.Url.ToString(), true);

    commanddelete.ExecuteNonQuery();
    myConnection2.Close();
}
```

Comment: You're leaving the page with the `Redirect` before you `ExecuteNonQuery`. Make the redirect the last thing you do on the page.

Comment: Bob thanks for the help! it works!

Answer (score 0):

maybe you are creating one string ID instead an integer

Try something like

```
commanddelete.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int);
commanddelete.Parameters["@id"].Value = Int32.Parse(customerID);
```